# Mass update or Bulk update Like product updates in Magento 1.9 for custom admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, massaction, bulk

I want to add Mass update or Bulk update Like product updates in Magento 1.9 for custom admin grid. Could you guys please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two thing you need to do inorder to get massAction in your custom grid.

> 1. Add `protected function _prepareMassaction()` to your adminhtml **Grid.php** file.
> 2. Add an action in your controller for each of your massAction options from grid. So that when you hit this action, all the selected records `ids` are passed to your controller action where you perform operation.

For more instruction about adding mass action please refer 
https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/

Hope it finds you helpful.